# Adding to Nautilus places

Tags: debian, nautilus

I am a sysadmin, and would like to add a location to nautilus "Places" or Bookmarks across all of my users. I am running Debian jessie, with GNOME classic. I have looked at user-dirs.defaults, but it seems that I can only remove what is already there, and not add anything new. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: bookmarks are saved in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temp user, write in the bookmarks.If you want to change some things in the tweak tool you can do that too. Then move the `~/.config` folder to `/etc/skel`.

Execute this code so that all user's have the same bookmarks and tweak tool configuration.

```
for i in `ls /home`; do su $i -c "echo $i"; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo ok; cp -r /etc/skel /home/$i/; cp -r /home/$i/skel/.* /home/$i/; rm -r /home/$i/skel; fi; done
```

This will also make sure new users have the same configs.